# Интрнет работает только через сервер

Tags: lan, сервер, сеть

Интернет работает только через сервер.Вчера еще до вечера все было нормально как потом просто интернет перестал работать,локалка работает на серваке тоже все ок,ели заходить на сервер удаленно то можно работать в инете,но на компах его нет,уже проверил и свич и интернет,дело в серваке я так думаю.Но заметил одно,что на тех компах где стоит НОД 32 постоянно выбивал вирус вирус,раньше такого не было,я в замешательстве,подскажите плиз))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть предположение что у вас Kido. У меня эта дрянь похожим образом убивала какую то настройку необходимую для Брандмауэра. Прогоните сервер антивирусом с глубокой очисткой. Если не поможет - откатите до последней контрольной точки восстановления. Если не можете это сделать - альтернативный вариант поставьте на сервер squid как прозрачный прокси. Для чего то более конкретного нужно намного больше информации.

Comment: спасибо попробую антивирус,у меня там стоит НОД 32 для сервака,он подойдет?

Comment: Главное антивирус а не SS

Comment: спасибо за советы буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Какая топология у сети? Т.е. как подключены компьютеры к интернету?
Глобально нужно локализовать проблему. Далее решать.

1. Проверить сетевые настройки
2. Проверить идут ли пинги
3. Изменить днс на 8.8.8.8 и 8.8.4.4
4. Потушить файрволлы, проконтролировать их настройки
5. Переустановить операционную систему

Comment: сетевые настройки уже проверенны вдоль и поперек,пинги идут,иначе как бы я подключился к удаленному столу,тоесть локалка есть ведь,ДНС не изменял так как на сервере нет днс,я его не настраивал,файрволлы не они тушил не помогло,заходил с другой ОС на компе их там просто две,результат тотже

Comment: Упала какаянибудь служба на сервере? Поясните технологию раздачи интернета сервером. Что за софт? Что за оси?

Comment: софт особенно не какого софта все встроенными средствами ОС Windows Server 2003

Comment: технология такая что сервер и есть роутером,на нем поставлены две сетевухи к одной инет от другой кабель в свитч,на той сетевухе что с инетом стоит настройка: разрешить другим пользователям сети... ,вот,а от свича уже идет кабель на все компы.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, на серваке 2 сетевых интерфейса, один - внутрь, другой - наружу. Проверьте настройки интерфейса, который наружу, должна стоять галочка Enable Internet Connection Sharing и должна быть выбрана правильная частная сеть. Это первое что приходит на ум при вашей проблеме...

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в Брандмауэр Windows/Общий доступ к Интернету (ICS) она была отключена ,я ее включил поставил что бы она перезапускалась но она все равно сама отключается!! инет работает со сбоями,что ее может отключать?